# Desktop image is not showing in Mountain Lion with dual monitor

Tags: macos, display, desktop

I have a MBA connecting via HDMI to Samsung Monitor.
Problem is desktop background for Samsung monitor is not showing. There is only grey desktop and doesn't have any changes even I try to change the image of the desktop at System Preferences.
Changes for the MBA desktop is ok.
Is that a mountain lion bug?

Comment: I have a somewhat similar setup (MBP and LG external) and haven't seen this problem when switching to Mountain Lion.  When you go to the "Desktop & Screen Saver" preferences, does it show you two dialogs...one for the main screen and one for the "Secondary Desktop"?

Comment: Grey screen...are you sure you're not running an app in full screen mode?

Answer (score 18):

Restarting the Dock seems to work for me, however I don't know what is causing this grey desktop background.

To restart the Dock, type this into Terminal and press enter:

```
killall Dock
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks. Pretty strange Mountain Lion bug.

Comment: Worked instantly, great tip. Have been wondering about this for months.

Answer (score 4):

OS X allows you to select different images for each display. When you open the **Desktop** section in *Desktop & Screen Saver* Preferences, you should get one dialog on each screen for choosing a desktop image. **Each dialog controls only the image for that screen, so make sure you're setting the image you want on both screens.**

Comment: This setting doesn't seem to save if I disconnect and reconnect the second screen (like when I leave from work and take the laptop home but plug it back in tomorrow).

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this problem and found this workaround:

- Open System Preferences -> Displays -> Arrangements
- switch on "Mirror Displays" and switch it off again

This is no solution for the problem of course, but at least the wallpaper is showing again without rebooting...

Comment: On MacOS Catalina, this is the only solution that worked for me.